# how do I close the engine created by sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlsoup to perform a simple query.
My question is how do I close the engine ?
thanks!

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup as SqlSoup

db = SqlSoup('sqlite:///test.sqlite')
res = db.people.filter_by(id = 1).all()

return res[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure why you think you need this, but here it is:

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.sqlsoup as SqlSoup
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite')

db = SqlSoup(engine)
res = db.people.filter_by(id = 1).first()

engine.dispose()

return res
```

use `Query.first()` not `Query.all()[0]`, create the engine separately from SqlSoup and pass it that engine.  You can dispose the engine afterwards.

Do note that a new pool is created when you dispose the engine;  the database is not perminantly disconnected, but any open connections are closed, and no new connections are drawn from the new pool by the dispose operation itself.